Throw ‘incorrectKeySize' error when create private key using CryptoKit EdDSA
I'm trying to Signature the privateKey according to this stackoverflow answer How do I generate a JWT to use in API authentication for Swift app, but with EdDSA algorithm.
The problem is, it always throw a incorrectKeySize error when create the privateKey. Keys are generated by openssl genpkey, do I need to do something else to encode that private key?
Below is the code:

Public/Private keys are generated in console through openssl genpkey:

    openssl genpkey -algorithm ED25519 -out ed25519-private.pem \
    && openssl pkey -pubout -in ed25519-private.pem > ed25519-public.pem


JWT code:

    struct Header: Encodable {
        let alg = "EdDSA"
        let typ = "ABCDEFGHIJ"
    }

    struct Payload: Encodable {
        let sub = "ABCDEFGHIJ"
        let iat = 1516239022
        let exp = 1516249022
    }
    
    private func createJWT_apple() async -> String? {
        do {
            let secret = "MC4CAQAwBQYDK2VwBCIEIE9dWdfSb3YjvA9gASX8ZY7BiQubC4jQLiwQZtUmHXrD" // This is a real key generated using openssl genpkey, but has been revoked.
            let data = Data(base64Encoded: secret)!
            let privateKey = try Curve25519.Signing.PrivateKey(rawRepresentation: data) //"incorrectKeySize" error throws here!
            
            let headerJSONData = try JSONEncoder().encode(Header())
            let headerBase64String = headerJSONData.urlSafeBase64EncodedString()
            
            let payloadJSONData = try JSONEncoder().encode(Payload())
            let payloadBase64String = payloadJSONData.urlSafeBase64EncodedString()
            
            let toSign = Data((headerBase64String + "." + payloadBase64String).utf8)
            
            let signature = try privateKey.signature(for: toSign)
            let signatureBase64String = Data(signature).urlSafeBase64EncodedString()
            
            let token = [headerBase64String, payloadBase64String, signatureBase64String].joined(separator: ".")
            return token
        } catch {
            printLog(error)
        }
        
        return nil
    }


I don't know swift (or apple) but: OpenSSL supports many public-key algorithms, so (since 2010) it uses PKCS8 format for private keys, which contains both an algorithm identifier with optional parameters (here ed25519) PLUS the algoirthm-dependent key data. (Similarly it uses the X.509/PKIX structure SubjectPublicKeyInfo for public keys.) A package that as here implements only one algorithm (at least only one signature algorithm) doesn't need algorithm identification and probably wants the 'raw' key, for ed25519 a 256-bit (32-byte) binary number.
